# How to map array of keys to object property types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to pass an array of keys and infer the return type from that, this is what I tried so far

```
type Obj = {
  cats: string
  dogs: string
}

type MapKeys<K extends [keyof Obj]> = {
  [P in K[number]]: Obj[P]
}

declare const obj: Obj

const cats: MapKeys<['cats']> = {
  cats: 'hi', // ok
} 

const catsAndDogs: MapKeys<['cats', 'dogs']> = { // error about the length but the types are ok
  cats: 'hi',
  dogs: 'hello'
} 

const getProps = (keys: [keyof Obj]): MapKeys<typeof keys> => keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({
  ...acc,
  [key]: obj[key]
}), {} as MapKeys<typeof keys>)

const getCats = getProps(['cats']) // the types are the whole Obj
const getCatsAndDogs = getProps(['cats', 'dogs']) // same error about the length
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#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)

Comment: In both `MapKeys` and `getProps` signatures, try replacing `[keyof Obj]` with `(keyof Obj)[]`. The former type denotes an array with exactly one member that is a key of `Obj`.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp Yes that did it, for `getProps` i used a type parameter to infer the array, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeffrey suggested, i switched the type in `MapKeys` to

```
type MapKeys<K extends (keyof Obj)[]>
```

and in `getProps` to

```
const getProps = <K extends (keyof Obj)[]>(keys: K): MapKeys<K> =>
  keys.reduce(
    (acc, key) => ({
      ...acc,
      [key]: obj[key],
    }),
    {} as MapKeys<K>,
  )
```